# Print column names literally in xtable

Tags: r, xtable

I am using xtable and want my column names to containt a . The reason is, that I want to copy this into Latex and have Special symbols avaible. I have tried this:

```
names(xt) = c("$\\kappa$", "$\\theta$")
print(xt, math.style.exponents = TRUE)
```

but my names read `\$$\backslash$kappa\$`. This is nice because in Latex it translates to exactly what I wrote. But I want special characters, so it's not so nice for me. Can I somehow print the titles literally, or something similar?

Comment: @user20650 Exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
print(xt, math.style.exponents = TRUE, sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
```

As pointed out in the comments, this argument needs to be added so that the sanitization doesn't mess the titles up.